# How can I make the mute command add a Muted role if there isn't already one? (discord.py)

Tags: python, discord.py

I recently started making a moderation bot for Discord servers, and I have all the basic commands. I made a mute command, but for most new servers, there isn't a muted role. Does anyone know how to add a role to the role list, and turn off send messages?

Comment: Have you tried any code? Adding this to your question and some errors and traceback will get you better and faster responses as long as it's a **[minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)**.

Comment: I'm still new to Discord.py and Python, so I don't know that much.

Comment: you can try to get role named "muted", if discord.py doesn't found the role it will return None, so you can use `if role is None` and then write a code to add a role called "muted"

Answer (score 1):

Use `utils.get` to get a role named `Muted`

If that role is None then create a role using `Guild.create_role`

```py
@bot.command()
async def mute(ctx, member: discord.Member):
    role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="Muted")
    if not role:
        role = await ctx.guild.create_role("Muted", permissions=discord.Permissions(send_messages=False))
    await member.add_roles(role)
```